# $\angle{B}=45^{\circ}$ in $\triangle{ABC}$, $D$ is on bisector of $\angle{A}$ and $AD=BC, \angle{ACD}=30^{\circ}$. Find$\angle{A}$.

Tags: geometry

[image]

background: chatting with people in mathematics problems group, and mentioning some geometry problems that no pure geometric approach being found, and someone gave this problem as an example.

motivation: To find a solution of this hard problem.

relevant definitions: Angle bisector, i bet all you know what it is.

source: No to my knowledge. Someone gave to me on social media group.

possible strategies: Need find a good construction. I can see extending AD and CD to meet the sides of the triangle, actually there are four points cyclic.

[image]

your current progress: I can get trigonometric equality from Ceva's theorem, and from making diagram it is easy to see the answer is 30 degree.

$sin(2x)sin(x+30^{\circ})=\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{4} $

why the question is interesting or important: because it is hard to construct a pure geometric approach to solve it.

etc: i cannot think of any etc yet.

Is there a pure geometric approach to solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Hopefully you’ll be able to read this with the help of the browser translator: https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/105111160?ADUIN=2735792907&ivk_sa=1024320u

Comment: Interesting geometric problem... Maybe the angle is 30, and it will be helpful if you set the point $P$ such that $P \in AB, PC=AC$.(with your first picture)

Comment: @timon92 Can you please take a look at this problem... thanks

Answer (score 1):

[image]

In the figure, if we reflect $D$ about $AC$ to get $Y$ as shown, we have $AY=BC$. Thus it suffices to prove that $\alpha=15^o$ when $AY=BC$, $\angle YCA=30^o$ and $\angle ABC=45^o$

Note that $\alpha \lt 60^o \implies AC \gt AY$ and $AY=BC \implies AC \gt BC \implies \angle CAB \lt 45^o$

[image]

In the second figure, it is obvious that $AE=CX$

The proof is based on the method of exhaustion. That is we prove that $\alpha \gt 15^o$ and $\alpha \lt 15^o$ are both impossible and hence $\alpha$ must be $15^o$

Assume that $\alpha \gt 15^o$.

We combine the $2$ figures as follows:

[image]

Note that $\angle EAY=\alpha-15^o$, $\angle BCX=2\alpha-30^o$

Also note that $A, B, X, C$ are concyclic and hence $\angle XCB=2\alpha-30^o$

Let the angle bisectors of $\angle XAB$ and $\angle XCB$ meet at $W$ and $CW$ cuts $AB$ at $Z$

Note that $A, B, W, X, C$ are concyclic.

Since  $\angle CAB $ is acute and $A, B, W, C$ are concyclic therefore $\angle CWB = 180^o -\angle CAB $ is obtuse.

Hence in $\Delta CWB$, $\angle CWB \gt \angle CBW$.

Consequently $\color{red}{BC \gt CW}$

$\Delta CXZ \cong \Delta AEY \implies AY=CZ$

Since we are given that $AY=BC$, therefore $BC=CZ$

But obviously $CZ \lt CW$

Thus  $\color{red}{BC \lt CW} $

The two statements colored red obviously contradict each other.

Hence $\alpha \gt 15^o$ is imposssible.

By similar arguments, $\alpha \lt 15^o$ is impossible.

Hence $\alpha = 15^o$

Job is done.

Comment: I see your approach. This reminds me of something: maybe you can construct a function on the angle and sides, such that it can only have one root as $15^{\circ}$. I have seen another problem proved in this way, instead of doing exhaustion and assumption. Let me try this way...

Comment: Let $f(x)=sin(2x)sin(x+30^{\circ})-\cfrac{\sqrt{2}}{4}$, easy to see $f(15^{\circ})=0$, and $f'(x)=2cos(2x)sin(x+30^{\circ})+sin(2x)cos(x+30^{\circ})>0$ when $0<x<45^{\circ}$. So there is only one root for $f(x)$ in $(0, 45^{\circ})$